# PyQt5: Connecting Signals from Working Thread to MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 for a GUI application where a QThread with a while loop is run after pushing a button. I would like to output some information about the process in the QThread class in my MainWindow's statusbar. Therefore, I was trying to use slots and signals to connect the two threads. However, the statusbar does not update.

I know that `window.print_status("Executed loop")` works in this minimal example but is not good practice and will crash in larger applications.

How do I properly connect my signal being emitted from a thread to the main window?

I attach a minimal example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from os import mkdir,path
from time import sleep,strftime,localtime
from shutil import copytree

ui_path = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(path.join(ui_path, "minimal.ui"))

class Communication(QtCore.QObject):
    signal_str = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        print("Start pressed")

        self.Thread = WorkingThread()
        self.Thread.start()


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)    
    def print_status(self,messagestring):
        print("Executing print_status with", messagestring)
        self.ui.statusbar.showMessage(messagestring)

class WorkingThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.signals = Communication()
        self.signals.signal_str.connect(window.print_status)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):

        #do something
        self.run = 1
        try:
            while self.run==1:
                #do some stuff in a loop
                #window.print_status("Executed loop")

                self.signals.print_status.emit("Hello World.")

                #sleep for a while and repeat
                sleep(30)
        except:
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #sys.stdout = open(path.join(ui_path, "logFile.txt"), 'w')
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is my ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>146</x>
      <y>176</y>
      <width>281</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Minimal Example</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>300</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Are you sure your code isn't stuck in `except: return` ?

Comment: Yes, it's being executed. I just replaced "return" with "raise" and get: ´´´self.signals.print_status.emit("Hello World.")
AttributeError: 'Communication' object has no attribute 'print_status````

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my mistake:

Instead of using:

```
self.signals.print_status.emit("Hello World.")
```

it should rather be:

```
self.signals.signal_str.emit("Hello World.")
```